# Appending timestamp in business objects scheduled reports

Tags: business-objects

Can we append timestamp in the format 'mmddyyyy' to business objects reports name generated by scheduler. I know we can append file extension using '%EXT%'. I am looking for something similar.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out this one:

I have to pass : RPT_NAME_%SI_STARTTIME%.%EXT%

This will generate only in yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss.fileextension format though

Answer (score 1):

The format of the returned date is defined by your default locale. This may be examined using the Regional Settings in the control panel.

[See this](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/boe_sdk/boesdk_dotnet_doc/doc/boesdk_net_doc/html/QueryLanguageReference161.html)